# How to change the color of the text of a QProgressBar with its value?

Tags: c++, qt, progress-bar

I don't know how to change the color of the text partially in the progress bar when its value becomes nearly 50%. This effect comes automatically in the fusion style progress bar (picture below). Does anyone know how this is done ?

[image: Fusion style progress bar]

Comment: What problems do you have with implementation, that described in provided link?

Comment: So you propose someone to write code instead of you? Stylesheets will not help you. It is a good point to learn basics of Qt.

Comment: What is the question? Anyone knows for sure how it is done. Most likely the one who wrote the Fusion style. But what do **you** want to know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had no idea how such a two colored text could be done, so I checked:

- [QFusionStyle::drawControl source code (Line 1452)](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qfusionstyle.cpp.html#1452)

```
QRegion rightRect = rect;
rightRect = rightRect.subtracted(leftRect);
painter->setClipRegion(rightRect);
painter->setPen(flip ? alternateTextColor : textColor);
painter->drawText(rect,
                  bar->text,
                  QTextOption(Qt::AlignAbsolute|
                              Qt::AlignHCenter|
                              Qt::AlignVCenter));
if (!leftRect.isNull()) 
{
    painter->setPen(flip ? textColor : alternateTextColor);
    painter->setClipRect(leftRect);
    painter->drawText(rect,
                      bar->text,
                      QTextOption(Qt::AlignAbsolute|
                                  Qt::AlignHCenter|
                                  Qt::AlignVCenter));
}
```

Basically the text is drawn two times into the same rectangle. Each time with an appropriate clipping.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the best, and probably the easiest, way to do this is to change the pallet for the QProgressBar widget:

```
    QPalette palette = progressBar->palette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, textColor)
    palette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, textColor)
    progressBar->setPalette(palette)
```

Answer (score 1):

"The setBackgroundRole method let you use a color role for the background, which means one of the predefined color of the style applied to the widget. So your are basically limited to the style and its colors."

[image]

Background solution:

```
    value = 65
    self.progressBar.setProperty("value", value)

    if value < 50:
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk { background-color: black; }")
    else:
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk { background-color: black; } QProgressBar { color: white; }")
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use stylesheet on the Container Widget :

```
myMainWidget.setStyleSheet(QString("QProgressBar {color: red}"));
```