# Qt Stylesheet: Controlling progressbar text highlight color?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

#### Context

I'm using a Qt stylesheet to customise a `QProgressBar` in my UI. I have a contrasting theme going on, which can be seen below:

[image]

I control this via my stylesheet:

```
QProgressBar {
    color: #FFFFFF;               /* Text color (not highlighted)
    border: 2px solid white;      /* Border color */
    border-radius: 5px;           /* Rounded border edges */
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 24px;           
    text-align: center            /* Center the X% indicator */
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    color: #204a87;               /* Highlighted text color!? Not working */
    background-color: #FFFFFF;    /* Color of the 'completed' bar */
}
```

#### Problem

Unfortunately, I find myself unable to change the highlighted progress text color once it is eclipsed or covered by the progress bar itself.

[image]

This can be seen above.

#### Solutions

I have attempted to see if I can set a *highlight* property for the text. I know that from the palette I *can* set a contrasting highlight color which makes the progress text label switch colors once the progress bar covers it. However, I can't find how to access that property here

```
QProgressBar::text::highlighted {
    color: #204a87; /* Doesn't do anything */ 
}
```

I also tried adding a color property to `QProgressBar::chunk` as you can see above. This also didn't do anything.

How can I set the contrasting highlight color for the progress bar label in the stylesheet? I've been looking mainly at [this Qt resource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) for guidance but it doesn't cover such a situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my own conclusion, there might be better answer.

According to the [progress bar's customization documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar), it seems that only  border, chunk, and text-align can be customized using style sheets. Even adding [`selection-color`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#selection-color-prop) doesn't work, because the text is not actually selected.

After trying out solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987469/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-text-of-a-qprogressbar-with-its-value), I concluded that

1. Qt does highlighting text in progress bar using painter, not in stylesheet
2. Any changes to the stylesheet will override the painter

However, there is a solution if you are willing to compromise, using `QPalette` and fusion style as followed

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QStyleFactory>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *central_widget = new QWidget{this};
    this->setCentralWidget(central_widget);

    QProgressBar *progress_bar = new QProgressBar{central_widget};
    progress_bar->setRange(0, 100);
    progress_bar->setValue(0);
    progress_bar->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("fusion"));
    QSlider *slider = new QSlider{central_widget};
    slider->setRange(0, 100);
    slider->setValue(0);
    slider->setOrientation(Qt::Orientation::Horizontal);
    connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged, progress_bar, &QProgressBar::setValue);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout{central_widget};
    layout->addWidget(progress_bar);
    layout->addWidget(slider);

    QPalette palette = progress_bar->palette();
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor::fromRgb(QRgb{0xFFFFFF})); // text, not highlight
    palette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, QColor::fromRgb(QRgb{0x204a87})); // text, highlight
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor::fromRgb(QRgb{0x0000FF})); // background, not highlight
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, QColor::fromRgb(QRgb{0xFFFFFF})); // background, highlight
    progress_bar->setPalette(palette);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

The fusion style has has the text centered in the progress bar. Text and background colors can be changed using `QPalette`, but you are giving up changing margin, border size, border color, border radius, and other properties.

Answer (score 1):

The code for `CE_ProgressBarLabel` in `qstylesheetstyle.cpp` simply draws the text using the `QPalette::Text` color role. It won't ever switch to another role, so indeed this can't be done with QSS. Another limitation of QSS. The fully flexible solution would be to write a `QProxyStyle` and style progressbars with C++ code, implementing `CE_ProgressBarLabel` (and whatever else we need) ourselves.